# What does the 'name' parameter do in flask-wtf's field definition?

Tags: flask

As per [Flask_WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) documentation, a 'name' is required when defining a field, as done in the example below:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    field_name = StringField('***name***')
```

I couldn't find any explanation of how this parameter is used. It's not required to render the field in the HTML file, where the Jinja2 syntax used is:

```
{{ form.field_name() }}
```

It's also not required in Python to retrieve the value inputted by the user, where the syntax used is:

```
value = MyForm.field_name.data
```

In fact my code works perfectly well even if I were to completely remove the 'name' parameter when defining the field. So, can anyone throw a light on where this parameter is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the label of field.

you can use it like this:

```
{{ form.field_name.label }}
```